# Which is the safer way to store `uint8_t*` C buffers in Rust?

Tags: c++, rust

I'm doing

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn receiveBufferAndPrint(buffer: *const u8, size: usize)
{
    for i in 0..size {
        println!("{}", unsafe { *buffer.offset(i as isize) });
    }
}
```

To receive an `uint8_t*` buffer from C.

What is the safest way to convert this buffer into a Rust object that deletes this memory when it gos out of scope? I need to deal with buffers safely on Rust but I don't want to copy the buffer element by element into a new Rust object, I want to wrap it into a Rust object that deletes it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: "According to Calling Rust method from C with array parameters, I can do" no you can't. The answer clearly says that you can't: "You should also **never, ever** use [T] or str when interacting with C code.".

Comment: If you don't know the size, them you should use `copy(src: *const u8, src_len: usize, dst: *mut u8, dst_len: usize)` and then use [`std::slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) to make a slice.

Comment: *"into a Rust object that deletes this memory"* - customarily across ffi boundaries, the one who allocated a resource should be the one to deallocate it. If the buffer was created on the C side, it has to be the one to dispose of it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If C is lending you the buffer, then use `std::slice::from_raw_parts`, and then you can copy that slice to `Vec<T>` or `Box<[T]>` if you want to keep the data.

If C is passing ownership of the buffer (i.e it's heap-allocated and C won't free it), then you can use [c_vec](//lib.rs/c_vec) crate to ensure it's freed properly (using `libc::free()` instead of Rust's own allocator).